# Removing all zero row "aaa[~np.all(aaa== 0, axis=1)]" is not working when run .py file in cmd?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to remove all row that is all zero. I followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11188364/remove-zero-lines-2-d-numpy-array) (as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25333988/remove-all-zero-rows-in-a-2d-matrix)) and tried the code directly in cmd, it worked well. But when I run the code from the file in cmd `>python myfile.py`, it does not work.

The code is only

```
import numpy as np
aaa = np.zeros(shape=(2,4))
print aaa
aaa[~np.all(aaa == 0, axis=1)]
print aaa
```

Nothing is removed. I got exactly same array between two print. Why is it not working via the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you're not updating `aaa`:

```
aaa = aaa[~np.all(aaa == 0, axis=1)]
```

It "works" in your terminal since the evaluation of that expression is printed to the terminal