# How can i remove the first n columns/lines with 0 values in a 2D matrix?

Tags: python, numpy

Referring to this previous question:

[Remove all-zero rows in a 2D matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25333988/remove-all-zero-rows-in-a-2d-matrix)

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[4, 1, 1, 2, 0, 4],
                 [3, 4, 3, 1, 4, 4],
                 [1, 4, 3, 1, 0, 0],
                 [0, 4, 4, 0, 4, 3],
                 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

data = data[~(data==0).all(1)]
print(data)
```

Output :

```
    [[4 1 1 2 0 4]
     [3 4 3 1 4 4]
     [1 4 3 1 0 0]
     [0 4 4 0 4 3]]
```

ok so far so good but what if i add null column?

```
 data = np.array([[0, 4, 1, 1, 2, 0, 4],
                  [0, 3, 4, 3, 1, 4, 4],
                  [0, 0, 1, 4, 3, 1, 0],
                  [0, 0, 4, 4, 0, 4, 3],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Output is

```
          [[0 4 1 1 2 0 4]
           [0 3 4 3 1 4 4]
           [0 1 4 3 1 0 0]
           [0 0 4 4 0 4 3]]
```

which is not what i want.

Basically if my matrix is :

```
            [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 4, 1, 1, 2, 0, 4, 0],
             [0, 0, 3, 4, 3, 1, 4, 4, 0],
             [0, 0, 1, 4, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 0, 4, 3, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

The output i'll be expecting is

```
        [[4 1 1 2 0 4]
         [3 4 3 1 4 4]
         [1 4 3 1 0 0]
         [0 4 4 0 4 3]]
```

Comment: What if you have null row or cols in between, like through the middle?

Comment: They should be left as is without change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach -

```
def reduced_box(a):
    # Store shape info
    M,N = a.shape

    # Mask of valid places in the array
    mask = a!=0

    # Get boolean array with at least a valid one per row
    m_col = mask.any(1)

    # Get the starting and ending valid rows with argmax.
    # More info : https://stackoverflow.com/a/47269413/
    r0,r1 = m_col.argmax(), M-m_col[::-1].argmax()

    # Repeat for cols
    m_row = mask.any(0)
    c0,c1 = m_row.argmax(), N-m_row[::-1].argmax()

    # Finally slice with the valid indices as the bounding box limits
    return a[r0:r1,c0:c1]
```

Sample run -

```
In [210]: a
Out[210]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 4, 1, 0, 2, 0, 4, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 4, 3, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

In [211]: reduced_box(a)
Out[211]: 
array([[4, 1, 0, 2, 0, 4],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 4, 0, 0, 4, 3]])
```

Comment: Works and accepted, can you kindly explain the code tho.

Comment: @Nelly Added comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `scipy.ndimage.measurements.find_objects`:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage.measurements import find_objects

data = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                 [0, 0, 4, 1, 1, 2, 0, 4, 0],
                 [0, 0, 3, 4, 3, 1, 4, 4, 0],
                 [0, 0, 1, 4, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                 [0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 0, 4, 3, 0],
                 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
data[find_objects(data.astype(bool))[0]]
#array([[4, 1, 1, 2, 0, 4],
#       [3, 4, 3, 1, 4, 4],
#       [1, 4, 3, 1, 0, 0],
#       [0, 4, 4, 0, 4, 3]])
```

Comment: I hadn't seen this function before, neat.